# How to configure activemq in wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, wildfly

So, I'm trying to configure the activemq to work in my wildfly 10 instance, but after following so many guides on how to do this I can't figure out why I'm getting this error when I start my jboss server.

List of my jar files modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\main
[image: List of my jar files modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\main]

My module.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.apache.activemq" slot="main">  
  <resources>  
    <resource-root path="."/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-amqp-5.14.5.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-broker-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-client-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-jms-pool-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-kahadb-store-5.14.5.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-mqtt-5.14.5.jar"/>        
    <resource-root path="activemq-openwire-legacy-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-pool-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-protobuf-1.1.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-ra-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="activemq-spring-5.14.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="commons-net-3.5.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="hawtbuf-1.11.jar"/> 
    <resource-root path="hawtdispatch-1.22.jar"/> 
    <resource-root path="hawtdispatch-transport-1.22.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="mqtt-client-1.14.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="proton-j-0.16.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="spring-core-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar"/>  
    <resource-root path="xbean-spring-4.2.jar"/>  
  </resources>  
  <exports>
    <exclude path="org/springframework/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/apache/xbean/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/apache/commons/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/aopalliance/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/fusesource/**"/>
  </exports>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
    <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
    <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

My standalone-full.xml configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
    <resource-adapters>  
            <resource-adapter id="activemq-rar">  
              <module slot="main" id="org.apache.activemq" />  
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>  
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">  
                    tcp://localhost:61616?jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true  
                </config-property>  
                <connection-definitions>  
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">  
                        <xa-pool>  
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>  
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>  
                            <prefill>false</prefill>  
                            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>  
                        </xa-pool>  
                    </connection-definition>  
                </connection-definitions>  
                <admin-objects>  
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/test" use-java-context="true" pool-name="test">  
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">  
                            queue/test  
                        </config-property>  
                    </admin-object>  
                </admin-objects>  
            </resource-adapter>  
 </resource-adapters> 
</subsystem>
```

And everytime I start my Wildfly 10 server I'm getting this ERROR

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "resource-adapters"),
("resource-adapter" => "activemq-rar")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0073: Failed to load module for RA      [org.apache.activemq]"
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

start your jboss server using standalone-full.xml

If you are on windows use the following command

```
standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml
```